# Execute script after outbound ssh

Tags: ssh

I want to execute a script after outbound ssh.

I have two servers (A) and (B), and a computer (C).

(C) can connect to (A) via SSH but can't connect to (B).

And (A) can connect to (B) via SSH.

But (C) can do multi-hop ssh to go to (B):

```
C -> A -> B
```

So I want to log the outbound ssh in (A) with this variable ${SSH_CLIENT%% *} to know if (C) do a multi-hop to connect to (B).

Comment: Which computer needs to know this? Do you want the running shell in B to know that it really originated in C, or something else? Do you have the user's cooperation, or are you trying to catch users who do this? And do you have root access to some of these computers?

Answer (score 0):

of course it is. because when you logged in using ssh you just run a new process of the service sshd which means you can open unlimited tunnel between C and B by A using ssh service also you can use crontab to make an auto-executed command and that after you logged out or close the connection with B.

Comment: Thank you.
i want to log the outbound ssh in (A) and not after logged out from B

Comment: Sorry i didn't got your point. please tell more about what are you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option would to simply rename the **/usr/bin/ssh** binary on **A** to **ssh.bin** and stick a wrapper shell script, called **ssh**, in the directory, that adds whatever logging you want before calling **ssh.bin** eg. [Shell scripting: Write message to a syslog / log file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-write-to-syslog.html)